# Display JSON on UITableView w/ Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am trying to display the captions of the Instagram Pictures from my feed onto a UITableView using Xamarin.iOS. Currently I am trying to load the Data via this function:

```
// The Request
            var request = new OAuth2Request ("GET", new Uri (defaultURL + "users/self/feed"), null, instagram);
            request.GetResponseAsync ().ContinueWith (response => {
                if (response.IsFaulted) {
                    Console.WriteLine ("Error: " + response.Exception.InnerException.Message);
                } else {
                    using (var stream = new StreamReader (response.Result.GetResponseStream ())) {
                        var json = (JsonObject)JsonObject.Load (stream);
                        // Console.WriteLine (json);
                        var jsonVal = JsonValue.Parse (json);
                        var username = jsonVal["data"]["username"];
                        // Console.WriteLine (username);
                        for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                            tableData.Add (new Instagram_Picture () {
                                Name = json ["data"]["username"]
                            });
                        }               
                    }
                }
            });
table.Source = new TableSource (tableData.ToArray ());
        table.ReloadData ();
```

I am using Xamarin.Auth to load the Instagram Account, and it loads perfectly and I can display the response in the Console. Here is how I am setting up the UITableView:

```
Instagram_Picture[] _category;
        public TableSource (Instagram_Picture[] category)
        {
            _category = category;
        }

        public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section)
        {
            return _category.Length;
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("TableCell");
            if (cell == null) {
                cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, "TableCell");
            }
            //show title
            cell.TextLabel.Text = _category [indexPath.Row].Name;
            //add accessory
            cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DetailDisclosureButton;
            return cell;
        }
```

I have created a Instagram_Picture class which is loaded within both of these other classes. However the real problem with all of this is that nothing is actually displaying on the UITableView. Your help will be greatly appreciated and Thanks beforehand!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Well its not actually displaying anything is there an alternate way

Comment: Have you verified that _category has data in it?

Comment: I am sending the data like this:

Comment: table.Source = new TableSource (tableData.ToArray ());
   table.ReloadData ();

Comment: Right, but have you actually verified that there is data using the debugger or Console.Writeline()?  What does _category.Length return?  You may also want to try the JSON.NET component, it is generally much better than the built in JSON libraries.

Comment: @Jason Could you please show me how I would construct my code accordingly to JSON.Net

Comment: the JSON.Net documentation has lots of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an override for the NumberOfSections:

```
public override int NumberOfSections(UITableView tableview)
{
  return 1;
}
```